# Typedoc "Unable to find any entry points"

Tags: typescript, typedoc

This is my "index.ts" file. It's actually called imports.ts here, I renamed it to index.ts after this but same error. The bottom terminal output shows what I write, 4 times, and about same error everytime:

[image: index.ts file and input]

Here is my tsconfig.json file:

[image: tsconfig.json]

Also typing "typedoc --out docs imports.ts" gives the same output of `error Unable to find any entry points. Make sure TypeDoc can find your tsconfig`

Not sure why tsconfig.json is not found...

Comment: The tsconfig was found - that error message could probably be improved... `"include"` in your tsconfig doesn't specify `imports.ts`, so it isn't included in the program.

Comment: Thank you, been chasing my tail for 2 hours trying to figure out what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Gerrit0 said: "The tsconfig was found - that error message could probably be improved... "include" in your tsconfig doesn't specify imports.ts, so it isn't included in the program"